# Set variable to maximum value in HiveQL

Tags: max, hiveql

I would like to obtain the first quartile of values from a column (speed) of data in table totalSpeeds.

To do this, I tried creating a variable (threshold), then selected values that were less than or equal to it.

```
SET threshold = (SELECT 0.25*MAX(speed) FROM totalSpeeds);
SELECT speed FROM totalSpeeds WHERE speed <= ${hiveconf:threshold};
```

This failed and returned a parse error. Is there a more efficient way of obtaining the upper-bound of the first quartile of speeds? Or is there a way of tweaking the above commands to return the first-quartile speeds?

Thanks in advance,

Anita

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in UDF in hive for calculating percentiles. use

> select percentile(speed, .25) from totalSpeeds;

explanation of UDF:

Returns the exact pth percentile of a column in the group. p must be between 0 and 1

Similarly we can extract multiple percentiles also by using percentile(speed, array(p1, p2))